# A relay for each terminal (live and neutral)

Tags: switches, relay, control, mains

I'm investigating a control circuit that switches a heating element. From what I can see there is a relay on both the neutral and live to the heater. The relays are controlled together and cannot switch independently.

Is this common for controlling a heating element? What is the advantage of this over just a single relay across the live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is normal to switch both poles of a mains circuit. That way, if the circuit is incorrectly wired (or plugged in, where 2-pole plugs are reversible!) you can be certain the circuit is not accidentally live when it is switched off.

What is NOT normal is to **fuse** both poles - if fuses are fitted, they should ONLY be in the live circuit, for hopefully obvious reasons.

Comment: What is important is to ensure that the neutral connection not be broken without the hot also being broken.  Breaking both hot and neutral is often somewhat safer than breaking just the hot, but breaking just the neutral is bad.  If one had a double-pole fuse which was designed so that an overcurrent condition on either side would disconnect both (e.g. both sides had contacts that were spring-loaded to open, but were held shut by a non-conducting piece of material that connected them) but I doubt such devices would be cost-effective in most applications.

Answer (score 2):

Another consideration in countries where the nominal AC power delivery is 110 or 120 VAC it is common to use both phases of the AC line to deliver 220 or 240 VAC to heater type loads.

This has the advantage of reducing the current requirement to deliver a certain amount of power to the load to half of what it would be at 110 or 120 VAC. It also reduces the wire size requirements as well.

In such instance both sides of the heater connection are HOT wires and so it is common for safety type reasons to use a two pole relay to cut off drive to a heater.