# Fixing logic for a relay-driven bidirectional AC Motor

Tags: relay, control

I'm trying to diagnose a relay control for a motor which was wired by someone else.

**QUESTION: How does this theoretically work?  What is it called?**

[image: picture of relay with wires]

Pictured here is the relay which controls a bidirectional motor.

[image: schematic of relay]

I believe the way it works is

- there are two poles for this single relay, represented by A1 and B1
- by default, when no control voltage is applied across terminals (C+/C-),

  - pole A1 is connected to A3
  - pole B1 is connected to B3
- when a control voltage is applied across terminals (C+/C-),

  - pole A1 is connected to A2
  - pole B1 is connected to B2

[image: schematic of wiring]

The confusing thing for me is the way this relay is wired: It seems like both circuits are never completed.

- **How does this theoretically work?**
- **Am I confused about how the relay works?**
- **Is the relay miswired?**

  - It seems like something should be connected to A2,A3,B2,B3. But what?

Comment: Possibly related: [A relay for each terminal (live and neutral)](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145114/a-relay-for-each-terminal-live-and-neutral?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One name for it is a 2-pole double-throw relay. The way it is apparently currently connected, it reverses the connections between a pair of wires connected to A1 and B1 and another pair of wires connected to A2/B3 and A3/B2.

For reversing a single-phase AC motor, it would reverse the connections to the main coil with respect to the auxiliary coil. It could also determine which of two coils a capacitor is connected to.

As pointed out by Tony Stewart, another relay is required to start and stop the motor. The direction would usually be selected prior to starting the motor.

Here are reversing circuit diagrams for a permanent split capacitor type (PSC) single-phase motor with either two identical windings or a dedicated auxiliary winding and for a universal motor.

[image]

There are other connection variations that could be used, but these three represent the main alternatives.

Comment: you drive a hard bargain; how could I not upvote hand-drawn schematics that actually do it right?

Comment: I revised the diagrams to label poles and terminals per relay diagram in the question.

Comment: I revised the diagram again to correct an error. Note that the relay could be connected with either A1 and B1 on the source side or A2/B3 and A3/B2 on the source side.

Answer (score 1):

Two SPDT latching? relays with a single bipolar coil which enables either Set or Reset. Forward or Reverse...

The poles go to the motor while the "throws" go to V+ and V- cross connected for bipolar motor direction power control.

Only doubt is how stop is selected before changing direction.

Comment: It seems like something should be connected to A2,A3,B2,B3. But what?

Comment: If 2 is NC (normally closed) while 3 is NO (open) then A2 MUST connect to B3 then to one battery polarity so you get exclusive OR 12V or 0V switched to motor while 0V OR 12V to the other contacts. These are the cross connects show as jumpers in schematics given in all other answers.

Answer (score -1):

I think your drawings are correct.

Think of it like this: to reverse the motor, you have to reverse the current going through the motor.

Your motor wiring looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhuxzY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

in this state, A1 is connected to the "positive" end of our voltage source, and B1 is connected to the negative one.

---

now, switching the state of the relais, the voltage now flows in the different direction through the motor, reversing its rotation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feg9GD.png)</sup>

Comment: Reversing the connection of an AC source does nothing. This would be correct for a DC motor if you erase "sine", "50 Hz" and the sine wave symbol.

Comment: @CharlesCowie ouch! yes.

Comment: oh wait, bidirectional AC probably means that yes, you can invert direction by inverting current – the phase of rotor vs stator field makes the difference.

Comment: Yes, reversing stator vs field makes sense for a universal motor, but that is not what your diagrams show.

Comment: I'd love to have proper motor symbols, but the diagram editor doesn't offer that. So, I could replace the "motor" text with "stator", would that make you happier :) ?

Comment: To represent a universal motor, you would need to show the stator and rotor is series. To represent a single-phase motor, you would need to show a capacitor in series with the aux winding or the capacitor connected to either of two windings. You would also need to show the power connections properly.

Comment: Exactly; although more correct, the comprehensive way to draw this diagram would only distract from the central fact, namely reversal of current, as long as I don't even have access to any motor symbols in this schematics editor. Hence, I'll just stay with the very superficial notion that these cables lead into the motor, and keep that block labeled as it is; sorry.

Comment: I don't think that a bad diagram is better than none; sorry.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I'd love to agree, but I simply have no way of improving this diagram, so please feel free to come up with your own answer or edit mine!

Comment: So my question then is: It seems like something should be connected to A2,A3,B2,B3. But what?

Comment: that depends on what part of your motor is actually connected to A1/B1, but I'd expect it to be your supply network

Comment: see @CharlesCowie drawings for details, by the way!

Comment: Thank you so much. I think your dialogue definitely improved the answer as well!