# why isolate the run capacitor from circuit when off?

Tags: induction-motor

Back in 8/24/2016 Charles Cowie answered a question regarding a bidirectional AC motor with hand sketches. At the top left corner, the run capacitor for a motor with 2 stator windings seems to "always connected" between these 2 windings. In this case, why not have it hardwired and need only a SPDT relay that selects which winding get energized vs. using a DPDT relay.

But in more than one occasion, I have seen circuits with on-off-on switches, not relay, that always disconnects the capacitor between these 2 windings when the motor is off.  Is there a logical reason behind it?

Comment: A link of the previus answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. For a reversible PSC motor that has two identical windings, the simplest way to reverse the motor is to connect the capacitor between the two windings and use a SPDT switch to select direction. A better scheme than that is to use a SPDT switch with a center off position so that the same switch can be used to start and stop the motor. [The previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254004/fixing-logic-for-a-relay-driven-bidirectional-ac-motor) was specifically about the possible wiring configurations using a DPDT relay. The diagram was intended to show how the mis-wired relay might have been intended to be connected.

The configuration described in the second part of the question may be intended to force a delay between forward and reverse operation. It could also be something done to accommodate a means of overload protection. There are a lot of single-phase motor configurations. A diagram of a specific configuration is needed to explain it.